# how to init data of class that exists in stl container?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, I have  class A:

```
 class A{
           int value_;
           public:
           A(A& a){
                value_ = a.value_;
           }
           A(int value){
                value_ = value;
           }
 };
```

I want a vector of class A but I'd like to pass a value to `A(int value)` for all of them.

```
 std::vector<A,allocator<A>> my_vector;
```

- What is the best way to do it?
- Is there a way by using allocator?

Comment: Just implement the default constructor?

Comment: Is your question "How can I construct a vector that contains some number of instances initialized to a particular value?" If so, use this constructor `explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );`. If not, clarify your question.

Comment: @KennyTM every time I need other value.

Comment: [explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
    Repetitive sequence constructor: Initializes the vector with its content set to a repetition, n times, of copies of value.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)

Comment: @David Schwartz but if my_vector is member of a class how I do it? I need it no in constructor of parent class

Comment: A::A(int value) : my_vector(...) { ; }

Comment: Your attempt to create a *copy-constructor* should accept a `A const&`, not just `A&`.

Comment: @David Schwartz sorry but what I need init the vector not in constructor?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The vector is initialized in the constructor -- it has to be, since it's a member of the class. If you want to change its value later, just change it however you want.

Comment: You cannot init data that already exists. You can init the vector to hold certain values, or you can change entries in the vector to different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> With the new standard added functionality was granted to objects of Allocator type.
>
> One of the features added was that Allocators now allows emplacement construction, aka. construction of objects using a *constructor* other than copy/move.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> template< class U, class... Args > void construct( U* p, Args&&... args );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> The standard does guarantee that STL containers must use this new feature, and with that said you could implement your own allocator just for the purpose of default initializing a *non-default-initializable* object.
>
> ---
>
> *<sup>It's not the prettiest solution, but whatever floats your boat..</sup>*

> [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)
>
> The allocator has nothing to do with that part of object initialization, it's only purpose is to allocate/deallocate memory, the type of initialization you are referring to is done elsewhere.
>
> The only constructor an allocator will call is the *copy-constructor* when someone asks it to perform a *placement-new*, and the value passed to that *copy-ctor* has already been established somewhere else.
>
> To sum things up; **No, you cannot use an allocator so solve this particular problem.**

---

#### when does std::vector require the use of a *default-ctor*?

`std::vector` only uses the *default-constructor* of the type it holds in two situations:

1. You specify the number of elements of your `std::vector` in the appropriate constructor overload but **doesn't** supply a default value
2. You use `std::vector<T>::resize (n)` and increase the number of objects in the container (note the lack of specifying the 2nd argument to the *member-function*)

---

With the above in mind we can do plenty of things using the container without supplying a default constructor in our object, like initializing it to contain *N* elements of value *X*.

```
struct A{
  A (A const& a)
   : value_ (a.value_) 
  { } 

  A (int value)
    : value_ (value)
  {}  

  int value_;
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<A> vec (5, A(1)); // initialize vector with 5 elements of A(1)

  vec.push_back (A(3));         // add another element
}
```

---

#### But I really want to be able to use *vec.resize ()*!?

Then you have <strike>two</strike>, <strike>three</strike>, four options:

1. Go with the *C++11* approach of using Allocators
2. make your object have a default constructor
3. wrap your object with a very thin wrapper who's only purpose is to default initialize the containing object (this might be easier said then done in some circumstances)
4. *"Wrapping [the object] in boost::optional practically gives any type a default ctor"* - @[Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo)

Comment: At the end you make very clear which option he should pick out of the two he has ;)

Comment: @honk I was in the middle of writing that section when I realized that there was some gibberish written in another section of the post, gibberish that would confuse the hell out of people.. therefore I decided to edit that part, and completely forgot about the list at the end.

Comment: @refp There's no problem with `resize`.  Just provide a value, as you do with the constructor.  There's really no place where `std::vector` requires a default constructor.

Comment: Wrapping in `boost::optional` practically gives any type a default ctor, so that might also be an option.

Comment: @JamesKanze maybe I should make it more clear that I'm talking about *resize* without the 2nd argument

Comment: @refp That sounds like a contradiction: you're saying you want to resize the vector using values constructed by the default constructor, for an object which doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not asking, OP is - and it's about when the container uses the *default-ctor*, not when I have the option to help it create an object.